# Intent not received by Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I'm trying to show a message when a user places a call using the standard android dialer.

I have the following code in my Activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
        setTestButtonListener();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Activity started...");

    }

    private void setTestButtonListener()
    {
    Button testButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked on test...");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence)"You clicked on the test button" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+150));
             MainActivity.this.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
             MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
             Log.i(LOG_TAG, "intent broadcasted... I think... ");
        }
     });
     }
```

Then in the BroadcastReceiver (well a class that derives from it):

```
public class OnMakingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = OnMakingCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName() + "_LOG";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
    {   
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, " got here!");       
    }
}
```

And then in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <receiver android:name=".OnMakingCallReceiver" android:priority="999">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I click the test button and I see this output.

Clicked on test...
intent broadcasted... I think...

And thats all. I expected to see "got here!".

Any ideas why I don't?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Also, ACTION_CALL_BUTTON is sent when you click on something that goes directly to the dialer. Are you sure you're doing that.

Comment: YES the receiver is defined to the manifest. No I want ACTION_CALL. I've updated the original post. What do you think? @joe

Comment: PS I also tried fully qualifying <receiver android:name=".OnMakingCallReceiver" And I also tried CALL_ PRIVILEGED.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in AndroidManifest.xml and it works. I think the key thing is the intent NEW_OUTGOING_CALL in the intent-filter.

```
<receiver android:name=".OnMakingCallReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_CALL" />  
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Probably ACTION_CALL could be removed. Also this may need to be added to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```